# Find the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{s^2}{s^3 -1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

> Find the inverse Laplace transform of 
>   $$F(s)=\frac{s^2}{s^3 -1}$$

What I've done is to decompose into partial fractions, so I got:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{s^2}{s^3 -1}\}=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{3(s-1)}+\frac{2s+1}{3(s^2 +s+1)}\}$$

By the properties of the inverse Laplace transform:
$$=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ \frac{1}{3(s-1)}\}+\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{2s+1}{3(s^2 +s+1)}\}=\frac{1}{3}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ \frac{1}{(s-1)}\}+\frac{1}{3}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{2s+1}{s^2 +s+1}\}$$
Where:
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\{ \frac{1}{(s-1)}\}=e^{t}$$

and 
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{2s+1}{s^2 +s+1}\}=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{2s}{s^2 +s+1}\}+\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{\frac{1}{s^2 +s+1}\}$$

How can I finish finding the inverse transformation?

> In Mathematica, the solution I've got is
>   $$f(t)=\frac{e^{t}}3{}+\frac{2}{3}e^{-t/2}\cos[\frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2}]$$

Comment: What if you wrote $s^2 + s + 1 = \left(s+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^2$?

Comment: Then, see item $20$: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf

Comment: You could always integrate by hand!

Comment: I think a key point to remember is that these computations are taking place over the complex numbers. In particular, every (nonconstant) polynomial can be factored into linears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s^3-1$ vanishes at the third roots of unity, $1,\omega,\omega^2$. It follows that
$$ \frac{s^2}{s^3-1} = \frac{A}{s-1}+\frac{B}{s-\omega}+\frac{C}{s-\omega^2}\tag{1} $$
and by residues:
$$ A = \text{Res}\left(\frac{s^2}{s^3-1},s=1\right) = \lim_{s\to 1}\frac{s^2}{s^2+s+1}=\frac{1}{3}, $$
$$ B = \text{Res}\left(\frac{s^2}{s^3-1},s=\omega\right) = \lim_{s\to \omega}\frac{s^2}{(s-1)(s-\omega^2)}=\frac{1}{3}, $$
$$ C = \text{Res}\left(\frac{s^2}{s^3-1},s=\omega^2\right) = \lim_{s\to \omega^2}\frac{s^2}{(s-1)(s-\omega)}=\frac{1}{3}, \tag{2}$$
then since $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s-s_0}\right)(x)=e^{s_0 x}$ we have:
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{s^2}{s^3-1}\right) = \frac{e^{x}+e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^2 x}}{3} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{3}e^x+\frac{2}{3}e^{-x/2}\cos\left(\frac{x\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}\tag{3}$$
as wanted.